# net::ERR_FAILED. Доступ заблокирован CORS

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

Столкнулся с проблемой, приложение на vps хосте не получает данные, но postman на доменной имя получает ответ от сервера. При этом приложение работает на локальной машине как надо.
Консоль выводит следующую ошибку:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at <Имя домена> from origin  'http://185.225.34.80:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local

AxiosError `user.js:36`

`POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/ net::ERR_FAILED`

user.js

```
export const loginU = (password,login) => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(`http://<ip_host>:5000/api/auth/`, { // Найденный ответ
                password, 
                login
            })
            dispatch(setUser(response.data.user))
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Не верный логин или пароль")
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Роут который обрабатывает запрос с клиента

auth.router.js

```
router.post('/', 
    async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {password,login} = req.body
        const user = await Courier.findOne({login})
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(404).json({message: `User with login ${login} not found`})
        }
        const isPassValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)
        if(!isPassValid) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'Invalid password'})
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({login: user.login}, config.get('secretKey'), {expiresIn: "1h"})
        return res.json({
            token, 
            user: {
                login: user.login,
                email: user.email,
                status_u: user.status_u 
            }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.send({message: "server error", e})
    }
})
```

И сам серевер

```
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/auth", authRouter)


const start = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(config.get('dbUrl'))

        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log("server started on port: ", PORT)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

start()
```

Пробовал пересоздать в mongodb домен хоста, менял CORS - все без результата.
Буду признателен за помощь

Comment: Извините ступил :) . Проблема в отправке запроса не на тот адрес. То есть вместо http://localhost:5000/api/auth/ = http://<ip_host>:5000/api/auth/

Comment: закройте вопрос, если проблема больше не актуальна